# Is there a way to perform a Firestore query that would work like `whereEqualToAny(field, list/array)`?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a requirement where in I need to query all documents with a field that can match any of the values inside a long list of strings.

Specifically this is for a newsfeed and post like feature. So each user will have a `posts`, `followers`, and `following` collection.

The newsfeed screen will then have a query of something like:

```
firestore.collectionGroup(“posts”)
   .whereEuqalToAny("postBy", [my.followers])
   .orderBy(“dateAdded”, SortOptions.DESC)
   .limit(10)
   .get()
```

This query would get all the posts from the current user's followers that matches the `postBy` field in any user's `posts` collection.

Comment: This is essentially an `OR` query, which is currently not supported by Cloud Firestore. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the recent updates, this is not possible using the `whereIn` query

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any